# If it is possible to use both wirless and usb tethering on my laptop?

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, internet, gaming, tethering

so as the title tell i'm wandering if i can use internet from usb tethering and wirless at the same time, well the point is i want just to boost my internet so i'm wandering if this is possible.
also using both actually worked i mean i'll attatched a photo for my pc where it seems that usb tethering and wirless connection actually work together on my laptop [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAHGi.jpg)

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "boost"? Do you want to improve reliability? Bandwidth? Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being connected to multiple networks simultaneously can problematic for most end nodes, especially for end users that don’t understand how IP routing works. To prevent issues, most mobile devices have a priority order for interfaces and disable all bit the most attractive, active one.

Even if you activated both interfaces simultaneously, only one would provide a “default route” out to the Internet, so only one would be functionally active anyway. To conduct any form of load balancing would require manual route management and an understanding about the implications for the return traffic.

If you want to learn more about this vexing issue, your search term is “multihoming.”

Source: [Phillip Remaker](https://www.quora.com/Why-can%E2%80%99t-I-use-my-Wi-Fi-and-USB-tethering-at-the-same-time-Whenever-I-turn-my-USB-tethering-option-on-it-switches-off-automatically-and-resets-USB-tethering-to-charging-only)

Answer (score 0):

Two networks have a priority order for interfaces and disable all bit the most attractive, active one. The “default route” will cross by selecting high priority, we can not connect internet between two network segments at the same time, but we can connect internet by UBS tethering and access resources on the same network segment in wi-fi.

As we know, wireless network and USB tethering work in different network segments.

We can set it as below:

for example, the USB tethering address setting likes this:

local IP address: 192.168.1.1

subnet mask:255.255.255.0

gateway:192.168.1.1

for example, the wireless network setting likes this:

local IP address: 192.168.42.129

subnet mask:255.255.255.0

gateway:192.168.42.132

We can set network discard as usual, now there are two gateways pointing to "0.0.0.0", so we need to configure the routing table.

1.Open command prompt as an administrator.

2.Type"route delete 0.0.0.0" (delete all the routing table of "0.0.0.0" ).

3.Type"route -p add 0.0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1" ("-p" means permanent or static, it prevents configuration from disappearing on next reboot).

4.Type"route -p add 192.168.42.2 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.42.132".

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be easier. You give both network and Static IP address and on one you leave the Gateway empty. Could be on both networks only one network has internet. That's how it works for me.